# How to remove a double Forward Slash from the end of a URL if there is one

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need help with removing a double slash from a URL entered by the user. This is for WordPress front end.

I have an option for users to input any link. Once they input/paste link in the value field, I need to add my affiliate code at the end of that link and show the final output (full link) with my affiliate ID.

This is the code I used.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="txtfullurl.value = txturl.value +'/affiliateid'">
URL : <input type="text" name="txturl" /> <br><br>
Full URL : <input type="text" name="txtfullurl"  > <br><br>
</form>
```

The problem is that the URL entered by the user might or might not have "/" (forward slash) at the end.

Therefore if the link has a double forward slash before my affiliate ID, I need to remove one.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is the Code

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="txtfullurl.value = txturl.value +'/affiliateid'">
URL : <input type="text" name="txturl" /> <br><br>
Full URL : <input type="text" name="txtfullurl"  > <br><br>
</form>

Comment: `$userInput = rtrim($userInput,"/");` to remove last forward slash from `userInput`

Comment: @LasVegasCoder... wrong. This will remove ALL forward slashes, not just the last one...

Comment: @patrick While you are correct, I think LasVegasCoder's suggestion would actually a viable option for the OP - my understanding is that they want to get rid of any trailing slashes so they can add their own when appending their affiliate ID... they just never considered the possibility that there may be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing any sort of sanitising or validation on the server. The most flexible solution is to make use of the `wp_parse_url`function, used in conjunction with `http_build_query`.

Example

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com//somethingelse';
$parsed_url = wp_parse_url($url);
$query_string = http_build_query([
    'affiliate_id' => 'my_id',
]);
$affiliate_link = $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_url['host'] . '/?' . $query_string;
```

Comment: Thank you for kind help. Didn't try this out yet. I will let you know once tried. By the way below I saw an answer to say use "trailingslashit()" I try to do that too. 

I will update you guys. !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`trailingslashit()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit) function to achieve this.

From the WordPress Codex, this function

> Appends a trailing slash.
>   Will remove trailing slash if it exists already before adding a trailing slash. This prevents double slashing a string or path.

Comment: Hi Hareesh, thanks for your reply. 

Honestly, I'm not pro with coding. 

Could you please kindly guide me littel bit more.

Lets say I need to use my above option to one of my page. 

After I place my codeing in that perticular page, where should I use this trailingslashit() function.

Can you give me an example in jsfiddle please.